# CF8's CFFEED quirks?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8, cffeed

Anything one should watch out for when using CF8's CFFEED tag?

Oh, here's a list...

- [Yet another post on cffeed and columnMap : Raymond Camden's ColdFusion Blog](http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/index.cfm/2008/8/21/Yet-another-post-on-cffeed-and-columnMap)
- anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// remove anything outside of explicit hex range (x20-x7F=standard chars,xA=carriage return,xD=line feed)    
reReplace(rssXml,"[^(!\x20-\x7F|\xA|\xD)]","","all")
```

Source: [CFFEED - You have failed me for the last time. : Raymond Camden's ColdFusion Blog](http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/index.cfm/2008/8/29/CFFEED--You-have-failed-me-for-the-last-time) , in a comment posted By [Nicholas](http://nicksollecito.com/)